# How to display all rows containing all query elements regardless of their location?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

i have entries:

```
[
  {
    text: "Le Paul Vens, 123123"
  },
  {
    text: "Vens Paul Le, 123123"
  },
  {
    text: "Vens Le Paul, 123123"
  },
  {
    text: "Denis Melnik"
  }
]
```

my request looks like this:

```
query = {"$text": {"$search": "\"Le Paul Vens\""}}
```

it outputs all entries where the phrase occurs:

```
Le Paul Vens
```

but I need to display all the lines where the phrase `Le Paul Vens` occurs, regardless of the location of each word.

how do i make a request?

Comment: Does searching without the `\"` give what you want? `{"$text": {"$search": "Le Paul Vens"}}`

Comment: @ray, thanks, that's what i wanted

Comment: @Joe, no, without quotes, it will search for each word separately in each line, but I need all three words to be on the same line.

Answer (score 0):

It could be simpler to search for 3 individual substrings.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $and: [
          {
            $ne: [
              -1,
              {
                "$indexOfCP": [
                  "$text",
                  "Le"
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            $ne: [
              -1,
              {
                "$indexOfCP": [
                  "$text",
                  "Paul"
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            $ne: [
              -1,
              {
                "$indexOfCP": [
                  "$text",
                  "Vens"
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/1rsOCyXu9I_)